# Blank response from api

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://api.xyz.com/go/login",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         crossDomain: true,
         dataType: "json",
         data:{id:'547',password:'password'},
         success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

             alert("success");// write success in " "
         },

         error: function (jqXHR, status) {
             // error handler
             console.log(jqXHR);
             alert('fail' + status.code);
         }
      });
```

This is the sample of code I used to get response.
what's wrong here?
The code isn't responding json file.

Comment: a response to a post request is not required to return a response body

Comment: i am sending login credentials via API and need to get a key which is used later in my website for further processing!
Blank respose is making me out of it!

Comment: What do the response headers / content say?

Comment: Does the `success` handler get called? Or the `error` handler? What does the response actually look like? What's it's status?